# Grails call ajax function before redirect?

Tags: ajax, grails

I have a controller that has an ajax function and a seperate action that redirects the page.  I want to know is it possible to make the ajax call when the link is clicked, but wait for the function to finish before the redirect action is called?

E.g.

```
<g:link controller="myController" action="myRedirectAction" before="saveData">link</g:link>
```

EDIT Added code

**controller**

```
def ajx_saveServiceGroup = {

    //Code to save data to object
    return
}

def saveConfigToRoLo = {

    //code to save object to DB
    redirect(action:"displayPDFSummary", id:orderId, params: [origSessionId: params.origSessionId, theSession: tempSession])
}
```

**gsp**

```
<g:link class="buttonSend" action="saveConfigToRoLo" id="${orderDataInstance.id}"  params="[origSessionId: origSessionId, orderId: orderDataInstance.id, submitToBT: true]" before="ajx_saveServiceGroup">Submit</g:link>
```

Comment: If you paste relevant code (controller/action and client side code) it would be easier for us to help you

Comment: I've added some code to show you what i'm attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a [remoteLink](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html) and then onSuccess callback you can change the windows.location to whatever you want !

A details description of what you are trying to achieve will help us provide better answers.

Comment: windows.location will not work as I need to call an action in my controller that performs a few procedures before the redirect.

Comment: Anyway redirects are transparently handled by XmlHttp objects - so if the action that is called by ajax completes its processing and then does a redirect - the ajax call will get redirected to another action. This way you have your first action complete the exection and your redirected action is invoked after that.